# Route for root address in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms, url-routing

i have following RegisterRoutes method in global.asax of my web forms application`

```
routes.MapPageRoute("about", "about", "~/about.aspx");
            routes.Add(
            "root",
            new Route("", new RootRouteHandler())
            );
```

The first route works ok i.e when i type `http://localhost:9898/about` but when i go to root address like 'http://localhost:9898' it does not invoke `RootRouteHandler`. this is the code for route handler

```
public class RootRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            var address = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["host"];
            string host = string.Empty;
            var index = address.IndexOf('.');
            if(index>0)
            {
                host = address.Substring(0, index);
            }
            var virtualPath = string.Format("~/{0}/default.aspx", host);
            var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Page;
            return page;
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**when i add route like

```
routes.Add("root",new Route("default",new RootRouteHandler());
```

then the handler is called fine for the address `http://localhost:9898/default` but i need to get it working for root address. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a new RouteBase in order to route for the host and override GetRouteData Method. Consider deriving from RouteBase and provide a functionality for host based route and add it to RouteCollection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase.aspx